# How to restore visual editor in WordPress

Tags: visual-editor

I am running WP Multisite in version 4.8

I have a site in the network that lost the visual editor toolbar a ways back (not exactly sure when it disappeared). When you go to Text view mode the content and markup is entirely visible. When you go to Visual view mode the content is there but white text on white background. Plus, the visual editor toolbar is missing all together.

I am running 18 plugins on this site -- none of which are TinyMCE, etc.

I have done all of the following:

- I uninstalled every single WordPress plugin in the site to test the visual editor -- no success the editor is not present
- I uninstalled the custom WordPress theme and replaced with the WP Twenty Seventeen theme to test the visual editor -- no success the editor is not present
- Googled the issue (there are numerous references and posts out there specific to the issue) and tried most all of theme to test the visual editor -- no success the editor is not present
- added `define('CONCATENATE_SCRIPTS', false);` to the beginning of my `wp_config.php` file to test the visual editor -- no success the editor is not present
- Logged into a number of other sites in my WordPress network to test the visual editor -- success, the editor is present

Anyone have this same issue?

Comment: Is your browser's error console reporting any javascript errors?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Milo

What is interesting is that the Super Admin can see the visual editor and gets this in the (chrome) console:

```
JQMIGRATE: Migrate is installed, version 1.4.1
wp-tinymce.php?c=1&ver=4603-20170530:25 Deprecated TinyMCE API call: <target>.onNodeChange.add(..)
```

But the normal Editor role user cannot see the visual editor and gets this in the (ie) console:

```
DOM7011: The code on this page disabled back and forward caching. For more information, see: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=291337
HTML1300: Navigation occurred.
DOM7011: The code on this page disabled back and forward caching. For more information, see: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=291337
JQMIGRATE: Migrate is installed, version 1.4.1
```

FYI, I did try to activate the TinyMCE plugin to see if I could get that WYSIWYG editor to work and it did not work so I ended up deactivating the plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Please check if your site is loading properly with SSL. I had my https setup with Cloudflare missing and some of the editor files would not load.